# Show/hide Gmap showing partially grey when showing

Tags: google-maps

I'm using a show/hide function to reveal the Gmaps google maps plugin but when the onclick is executed the Gmap is shown but part of the map is missing and is greyed out.

I've looked online at various sites for a solution and only found the option to use "gmap.checkResize()" but not sure how to go about to use this with my code, and if it will even work for my problem...

I've added the code below and am looking for assistance with getting the whole map to show when onclicked.

```
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=ABQIAAAAL7_5Aste4KkbgvT91y3k9xQo4D0inr193z9lVfCY1TNJb6Lz5RQJyM7R-PR3bMS1i_GvwioUrJMaXw" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery.gmap-1.1.0-min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <style>
    #map{
                    position:relative;
                    float:left;
                    width:450px;
                    height:400px;
    }


    .PlaceHeading{
        color: #C6688D;
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 15px;
        margin-bottom:-13px;
    }

    #content{
        text-align:center;
    }

    a{
        color: #C6688D;
    }

    .PlaceAddress{
        color: #666666;
        font-family: Arial,Georgia,sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: normal;
    }



    </style>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
    $("#map").gMap({ markers: [{ address: "809 1st Ave. N.E. Calgary, Alberta",
                                 html:'<div id="content"><center>'+
                                    '<h1 class="PlaceHeading">Blue Star Diner</h1>'+  //*Title of location
                                    '<p class="PlaceAddress">809 1st Ave. N.E.<br />'+ //*Street address of location
                                    'Calgary, AB <br />'+ //*City and Province of location
                                    '403-261-9998 <br/>'+ //*Phone number of location
                                    '<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=809 1st Ave. N.E.+Calgary,AB+Canada" target="_blank">'      //*Enter Address info in url where appropriate to link to Google directions page
                                    +'Get directions</a> <b>|</b> <a href="http://www.bluestardiner.ca/" target="_blank">' + //*Enter place url here
                                     'Visit website </a> </p></center>' +
                                     '</div>',
                                      icon: { image: "mapPage/images/marker1.png",
                                      iconsize: [25, 41],
                                      iconanchor: [9, 34],
                                      infowindowanchor: [9, 2] }
                               }],
                               zoom: 13 });
    });
    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript">
    function ShowHide(divId)
    {
    if(document.getElementById(divId).style.display == 'none')
    {
    document.getElementById(divId).style.display='block';
    document.getElementById("expandMap").src="mapPage/images/minus.jpg";
    document.getElementById("mapText").innerHTML="Hide map";
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementById(divId).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("expandMap").src="mapPage/images/plus.jpg";
    document.getElementById("mapText").innerHTML="View map";
    }
    }
    </script>





    <body>

    <a onclick ="javascript:ShowHide('HiddenDiv')" href="javascript:;" ><img src="/mapPage/images/plus.jpg" id="expandMap"alt="" style="float:left;" /><p id="mapText">View map</p></a>

    <div class="mid" id="HiddenDiv" style="DISPLAY: none" >
    <div id="map">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

`display: none;` means that the element is taking up no space on the page which seems to cause the GMap size calculations to not work properly. Using `visibility: hidden;` instead is one way to fix it. `position: absolute;` can probably help you out if the element taking up space is an issue.